# Selenium Webdriver Java: Start the Chrome Browser with Extensions and my configuration

Tags: java, selenium

Sorry for my bad English.
I have a question on webdriver+chrome+extension.
I need to test a load time of 100 sites with or without many extension like adblock.
I program in Java.
The problem is:
When i add the extension whit .crx, with this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

the chrome start with a "clear" adblock configuration.

Whereas I need the max restrictive configuration, that I configure in my chrome manually.

How can I start new chrome instance with extension with my configuration?

Comment: Extensions use the local storage to store the settings. You could restore the local storage via selenium, or set the setting via URL if the extension allows it, or repack the extension with the expected settings, or use an existing profile were the extension is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

this is my new code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\P\\Desktop\\progetto tesi\\chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\P\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

            driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);// Aspetta 30 secondi prima di catturare un eccezione.
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start chrome with your entire profile. Below example is for windows. You need to put your own username in the path. In linux just alter path to user data.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/YOUR_USERNAME/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! 
so for example, if i use this instruction, I find in new chrome instace all my extensions? whit configuration?

Comment: ok! now i test your solution!
there are the extensions but I have a problem! 
when the browser start, It load the home page, and load also the google little box and the google search(the default chrome home page !) !
the loading of the little box result in the total load time!
so i need a solution that allow me to execute a chrome home page empty but with extensions.

Comment: I don't really know what is "google little box". Can you elaborate exactly what is happening and when? What should happen instead? Probably some screenshot could help?

Comment: when I launch whit your code,appear this box:
[link](https://ibb.co/j2j5uQ)
the chrome have the extensions but have also the littles boxs.
the littles box influence the load time!
Wherease with this code, not appear the little box but there aren't the exstensions:
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Paco\\Desktop\\progetto tesi\\chromedriver.exe");
driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
[link] https://ibb.co/fmDb15
i need, if possible, the google istance without anythink but with the extensions!!

Comment: Why this influence the load time? Could you show what you are trying to achieve? You should start measuring time just before you execute driver.get(); not on chrome startup.